# Connecting to postgresql on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

I have an issue connecting to my local postgresql database. It seems like I retrieve all the tables and other information in my Server Explorer, but sadly everytime I compile I get an exception that says

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
 Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'host'.
```

Here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DBVSHotel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var con = new SqlConnection("User Id = postgres; Host = localhost; Database = Hotels; Initial Schema =public");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for connection strings here is where you need to look in regards to how to configure a proper connection when connecting to PostGress 
[C# ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/)

Comment: You need to install the NpgSql package. The System.Data.SqlClient is for MSSQL server, not Postgresql.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the Npgsql provider and new `NpgsqlConnection`, `SqlConnection` is for Microsoft SQL Server.

http://www.npgsql.org/doc/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the conection  string (the word host is not a parameter)

```
connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
var con = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
```